# How do I get the same installed programs list as Programs and Features?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

The program populates a list with the installed programs from the registry keys.  It reads two places.

> *SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall* 
>   *SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*

Problem is, the list that I get is way longer than what I see in *Programs and Features*, what are the rules used to filter which program should be displayed or not?

Comment: Don't query the registry, this is not a supported scenario. Instead use the Windows Installer: [Using Windows Installer to Inventory Products and Patches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369558.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to accomplish this, Win32_Product, Registry Search etc.
Have you tried searching online before posting?

See this :
[C#: How to get installing programs exactly like in control panel programs and features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524161/c-how-to-get-installing-programs-exactly-like-in-control-panel-programs-and-fe)

There's another good discussion here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94c2f14d-c45e-4b55-9ba0-eb091bac1035/c-get-installed-programs