# Get Add Remove Programs List Exactly As Shown In Windows C# Framework 3.5 (Not 4.0)

Tags: c#

I have tried this approach to get the list of add/remove programs and it still does not give the exact list

Look in at the registry in 3 places

```
installedSoftware.AddRange(GetInstalledSoftware(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"));
installedSoftware.AddRange(GetInstalledSoftware(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"));
installedSoftware.AddRange(GetInstalledSoftware(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"));
```

Code:

```
private List<string> GetInstalledSoftware(string regKey)
{
    var installedSoftware = new List<string>();

    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regKey))
    {
        if (key != null)
        {
            foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                {
                    object displayName = subkey.GetValue(ToolResources.DisplayName);

                    if (displayName != null)
                    {
                        installedSoftware.Add(displayName.ToString());
                    }
                }
           }
       }
    }

    return installedSoftware;
}
```

This is a 4.0 solution but will NOT work in 3.5

[C#: How to get installing programs exactly like in control panel programs and features?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524161/c-how-to-get-installing-programs-exactly-like-in-control-panel-programs-and-fe)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the autoquery of 32/64 bit keys. If you have .net 4 you can force 32 bit applications to query for x64 keys by using the **RegistryView.Registry64** attribute

```
var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
using (var key = hklm.OpenSubKey( key ))
{....}
```

if you want to use the same functionality in .net 3.5 you will have to write quiet some code. See this article for a solution:  [Query Registry With .net 3.5](http://www.rhyous.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa/)

*"This can also be done in .NET 3.5 and prior but it is not easy.
 We have to do use a DLLImport and use RegOpenKeyEx, RegCloseKey, and RegQueryValueEx. Here are some examples."*